# iOS: UITableView reloadData can not refresh data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

UITableView not reloading data. I am using **pull to load more** library to load data on scroll

I have tried

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.pullTableView reloadData];
});
```

and

```
[self.pullTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) 
                                     withObject:nil 
                                  waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it's not reloading?  Maybe the data just hasn't changed.

Comment: Post some code regarding how you are maintaining your data after 'pull to load more'. Seems like an issue with that only. Try putting a breakpoint on `[self.pullTableView reloadData];` and check your data.

Comment: Is new data being loaded when you reload the screen?

Comment: Data updating in iOS 7 but not working in iOS 8

Comment: show me your full coding

Answer (score 1):

`reloadData` won't actually fetch data of the internet or your datasource from you, it will just call back the function of `numberOfSection` `numberOfRowInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Before calling reload data, you should call the method that go and fetch the new content, then call reloadData

Put your entire class view controller code if you want more help.

Comment: After fetching data I have tried it. Already data is in array from which I am showing data to table

Comment: As a I said, since ther can be many reason, you'll have to show more code if you want help. It's hard to simple guessing what can go wrong with such little information :)